# Telegram bot initiate conversation with a user

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am writing a Telegram bot, to simplify the issue let's say you can ask the bot questions in a channel and it replies to you in private. When the bot receives the command it takes the `chat_id` of the user from: `update.message.from_user.id`

But when I do this I get an error:

```
Unauthorized: Forbidden: bot can't initiate conversation with a user
```

This sounds quite logical, as I assume this prevents from writing spam bots. The question is how do I overcome it? How can I let the user enable private messages from the bot?

**Note:** The bot does succeed sending messages to me but not to other users.

Comment: Why don't you just send them bot username?

Comment: What do you mean by send them bot username?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Telegram Bots can't initiate a conversation with a user.**
Only an user can initiate it by clicking on the *start* button. There is no way to around this.

In your case, you can ask the user to start the bot **before** asking questions in the channel, for example by attaching a button containing the bot URL (https://t.me/bot_username).

Comment: In that solution we are not sure that specific user pressed the button, right?

Comment: @Pumych when a user presses a button, you receive a CallbackQuery update / object; you can check the `form` field for checking which user clicked on the button. Anyway, if it's a URL button, you can't tell, but you can see who issued the /start command to your bot.

Answer (score 0):

message.from_user.id

try instead

message.chat.id