How to send a message to a telegram user in response of a callback he did?
I'm implementing some Telegram bot to manage some booking of shuttle for a small paragliding company.
Basically, the bot will publish a message in a Channel saying that there a few available times, then the user can click on one of the available time, and I want to answer him(personally) that its registration has been successfull(or not), and with another callback button to allow him to release the spot.
Here is my current code:
var botClient = new TelegramBotClient("BOT_TOKEN");
using CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

ReceiverOptions receiverOptions = new()
{
    AllowedUpdates = Array.Empty<UpdateType>() // receive all update types except ChatMember related updates
};

botClient.StartReceiving(
    updateHandler: HandleUpdateAsync,
    pollingErrorHandler: HandlePollingErrorAsync,
    receiverOptions: receiverOptions,
    cancellationToken: cts.Token
);

//POC Only, send a message to the channel to provide available shuttle
var me = await botClient.GetMeAsync();
InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new[]
{
    // first row
    new []
    {
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "13:00", callbackData: "register;13:00"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "14:00", callbackData: "register;14:00"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "15:00", callbackData: "register;15:00"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "16:00", callbackData: "register;16:00"),
        InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "17:00", callbackData: "register;17:00"),
    }
});

Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    chatId: "@MyChannelName",
    text: "Here are today current shuttles times, click on a button to register",
    replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
    cancellationToken: cts.Token);
Console.WriteLine($"Start listening for @{me.Username}");
Console.ReadLine();

// Send cancellation request to stop bot
cts.Cancel();


async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

    // Only process Message updates: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
    if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
    {
        await HandleCallBackQuery(botClient, update.CallbackQuery, cancellationToken);
    }
    // ....
}


Task HandleCallBackQuery(ITelegramBotClient botClient, CallbackQuery callbackQuery, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received callback data:" + callbackQuery.Data);
    botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(callbackQuery.Id,"Thanks for registering"); //This is only a toast and don't allow any callback or historic, it's easy to miss
    //I would like to send him a message:
    // InlineKeyboardMarkup inlineKeyboard = new(new[]
    // {
    //     new []
    //     {
    //         InlineKeyboardButton.WithCallbackData(text: "Unsubscribe", callbackData: "unregister;13:00"),
    //     }
    // });
    // Message sentMessage = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
    //     chatId: chatId,
    //     text: "You are registered. Please unsubscribe if you cannot join us anymore",
    //     replyMarkup: inlineKeyboard,
    //     cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

How can I retrieve a chatID for this user(and what scare me the most: will it work if the user never directly texted this bot?)

You can't initiate a private session like that (for obvious reasons). Have the user initiate the private session (from a link in the channel) and then communicate in the private chat from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49965738/telegram-bot-initiate-conversation-with-a-user

@Eddy Since I'm answering a callback of the user, I was hopping it would be considered as "the user did initiate the exchange".

In the update object, you have access to a unique chat ID, you can fetch it from the delegate parameter and pass it. If the user never directly texted this bot, I think you can`t start to chat as a bot currently.
  async Task HandleUpdateAsync(ITelegramBotClient botClient, Update update, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
     //CallbackQuery has this field.
        if (update. Message is not { } message)
            return;
        var chatId = message.Chat.Id;

in your case since you are invoking the call back from channel you should use From property
Task HandleCallBackQuery(ITelegramBotClient botClient, CallbackQuery callbackQuery, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
 var chatId = callbackQuery.From.Id;


That doesn't work for callback queries, right?

@J4N You have access to the "message.chat.id" in CallbackQuery

I just tested, I do not, probably since the callback is from a message that is in a channel

@J4N Correct I Just updated my answer, I checked the code, and it is working. The "message" was null in the case that I was calling from channel, And I have access to caller user in the "From"
